# Syncronizing validation values between layers

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a question regarding data validation between layers. As an example, let's say I have an object called Book with a string property called Title.

In the DB I have a specific length for Title, which will dictate how many characters I can store in my Title property.

I am validating requests between each layer in the application. So I validate the user input in the presentation layer, validate the service calls to my application layer and the SQL data base will obviously validate the data before I attempt to insert it.

My questions is, if I have a limited length to the Title property, what is the best way to communicate this through each layer. If SQL Server says that length cannot be more than 40 characters, what is the best way to tell the other layers this without having to hard code the length value into each one of them.

What do you guys do in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

First off:

> the SQL data base will obviously validate the data before I attempt to
>   insert it

No, it won't.  If you are passing it via a parameter, it will be truncated.  If you are running a direct sql statement then you will receive an error *after* you run the insert.

That said, we add validators to our objects via attributes and let the Enterprise Library validation kick off prior to attempting to pass the data to our db server.  This allows us to customize the message per property and in multiple languages.

**Example:**

```
  using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation;
  using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators;

    namespace MyApp.ObjectModel {
      public class Account {
        private String _accountNumber = String.Empty;
        [StringLengthValidator(1, 50, MessageTemplateResourceName="ValidationStringLength", MessageTemplateResoourceType = typeof(MyApp.Properties.ErrorMessages), Tag="Account Number")]
        public String AccountNumber {
          get { return _accountNumber; }
          set { _accountNumber = value; }
        }


        protected Validator BuildValidator() {
          return ValidationFactory.CreateValidator<Account>();
        } // method::BuildValidator


        public String Validate() {
          Validator internalValidator = BuildValidator();
          ValidationResults info = internalValidator.Validate(this);
          String result = String.Empty;

          if (!info.IsValid) {
            foreach(ValidationResult vr in info) {
              result += vr.Message;
            }
          }
          return result;
        } // method::Validate


        public Boolean Save() {
          if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Validate()) {
            // perform the save operation.
          } else {
            // do something else, log the message or send it back to the screen or whatever.
          }
        }
      } // class::Account
    }
```

The above class is a very simple example of using the Enterprise Library validators.  The main things to take away from this are the attribute on the AccountNumber property which basically says the account number must have between 1 and 50 characters.

We placed the Validate() method in a base class that gets called whenever we go to persist the data.  Also our validate method actually returns a collection of the errors which we filter up to whatever is trying to save the object. Next, we use an Inversion of Control pattern for passing the appropriate data layer interface to the object itself.  This way, again, we can keep the objects save logic within itself while still supporting mocking capabilities as well as the ability to swap out persistence mechanisms (ie: database servers) at will.  This is not represented in the code sample above.

Essentially this allows us to keep the validation logic within the business class while every other layer can be ignorant of it and simply filter any errors to the appropriate place (usually a message area on the screen).  If you have specialized validation logic, it is pretty trivial to add custom validators and sprinkle the attributes whereever they are needed.

The final thing is that each layer can call the validate() method at any time, not just during a save op, to ensure data consistency.

Comment: Ok so how do you deal with the values such as max length? If you have a max length of 10 for a field in your database, will you hard code the value 10 into your layers? Or do you use a central configuration?

Comment: @ChrisPaynter: 10 is baked into the class definition.  All of the layers depend on the object to determine if it is valid or not.

Comment: Ah great thanks. So I'm guessing you are using a public const int for that?

Comment: @ChrisLively Can you support your answer with an example? I mean update your answer containing an example of how the other layers depend on the object for which you have set the attribute. That would be a lot more clearer...

Comment: @ChrisPaynter: No.  See update I think the code sample will make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is an out of the box solution that will do exactly what (i.e. tie in your domain validation to your db)

But with some smart we can implement something that will save you loads of extra work.

I would recommend looking at using a framework like [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

This will allow you to create a validation class which you can use to validate your domain models throughout your application layers.

So, you will only need one validation class per model and then of course the DB will let you know of any problems at that level.

Alternatively if you need to, you could create one validation class per layer, per scenario or really however you want.

Have a look at some implementation code from CodePlex below:

```
using FluentValidation;

public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Company).NotNull();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(customer => customer.HasDiscount);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).Length(20, 250);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode).WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
  }

  private bool BeAValidPostcode(string postcode) {
    // custom postcode validating logic goes here
  }
}

Customer customer = new Customer();
CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customer);

bool validationSucceeded = results.IsValid;
IList<ValidationFailure> 

failures = results.Errors;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have a mechanism that allows me to validate my entities before hitting the database.(in UI and business layer)

**Why?**

well databases usually don't tolerate any violation of the defined schema and they usually throw exceptions that is really bad specially if you are working with a persistent framework like NHibernate or Entity Framework.(These frameworks usually use the unit of work pattern and try to do all the stuffs in one shot and if something goes wrong there's no guaranty that you can have that shot again :) )

**How ?**

In most solutions this means Meta Data (xml config files or .net Attributes)
and that means making these meta data synchronized with the database.MVC Framework has such a mechanism out of the box which in my opinion is pretty cool
I have never seen an alternative to this meta data solution but maybe we can build the metadata on the fly using the actual schema of the database.

The policy of alerting the user of these violations can be different.
Some prefer to alert the user right away as something goes wrong(validate by field)and some prefer to alert the user after she has provided all the data (validate by form) but one thing is clear :There should be a single infrastructure responsible for validating the model in both cases and this infrastructure should be independent of the model thus it can be reusable.